# Delete Empty Excel Files in a Folder in different extensions

Tags: excel, vba

i have found this vba code and applied in my excel workbook to delete empty excel files in a folder path in given this code here this vba code is not deleting any empty excel files in a given folder path
why it's not deleting any empty excel files in folder i don't understand

this is my folder path

C:\Users\Visshnu\Desktop\Excel Files

in this folder i have excel files in two different extensions one is .xlsm and another .xlsx

i have applied code like this

```
Sub DeleteEmptyFiles()
 Dim FolderPath As String, Filename As String, wb As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet, boolNotEmpty As Boolean
 Dim previousSecurity As MsoAutomationSecurity

 FolderPath = "C:\Users\Visshnu\Desktop\Excel Files\" 
                                           
 Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsm*","*.xlsx*")

 Do While Filename <> ""
    previousSecurity = Application.AutomationSecurity
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderPath & Filename)
    Application.AutomationSecurity = previousSecurity
    
    boolNotEmpty = False
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.UsedRange) > 0 Then
            boolNotEmpty = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
    wb.Close False
    If Not boolNotEmpty Then Kill FolderPath & Filename
    Filename = Dir()
 Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot use `Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsm*","*.xlsx*")` like this. Please have a look at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function Also try to understand how to use a wildcard in a path- resp filename.

Comment: `For Each ws In wb.Worksheets` Er, what if there is a Chart Sheet or Macro sheet in the workbook?

Comment: Maybe the OP's definition of empty workbook is like that. If there  are only empty worksheets then the workbook is empty ;-)

Comment: Maybe... And hence I asked the question. Otherwise few Checks to see if the file is empty **1.** Check if sheets (not only worksheets) are empty **2.** Check if there is VBA code? (I have lot of files which are empty but have VBA code stored)

Comment: Hmm, seriously, IMHO it's difficult to find out whether a workbook is empty as there might be cell formats left in the file etc. but no data at all and the the OP's check would return _not empty_. And by difficult I mean you hvae to do a lot of more checks than the OP. But if that is sufficent for the OP's need ... fine with me :-)

Comment: I have found this code in Google search i am not a expect in excel VBA i have some excel workbook with empty no data  in that folder i have given above

Comment: In that folder i have 2 different extension excel workbook files  is .xlsm .xlsx

Comment: As written, if it is fine for you just to check for the worksheet on `UsedRange`  then go ahead. Just be aware that you might also delete files which might contain other stuff and that you migh not delete files which you consider as empty because `CountA(ws.UsedRange)`  is `>0`

Comment: If there are only file with XLSX or XXLSM you can remove the check on the extension in the fix I provided. But you can also leave it in the code. It will not hurt. BUT you have to use DIR as I did in the code. You cannot just add other file extensions resp. wildcards as a second or third parameter.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix of your code would be

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteEmptyFiles()
    Dim FolderPath As String, Filename As String, wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, boolNotEmpty As Boolean
    Dim previousSecurity As MsoAutomationSecurity

    FolderPath = "C:\Users\Visshnu\Desktop\Excel Files\"
    FolderPath = "D:\TMP\"
 
    ' Take all files with extension xls which also inlcude xlsb  etc.                                             
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*") ' , "*.xlsx*")
      

    Do While Filename <> ""

        Dim ext As String
        ' retrieve the extension of the file which Dir returned
        ext = Right(Filename, Len(Filename) - InStrRev(Filename, "."))
        
        ' Check if the extension is XLSX or XLSM 
        ' because these are the extensions we are after
        If UCase(ext) = "XLSM" Or UCase(ext) = "XLSX" Then

            previousSecurity = Application.AutomationSecurity
            Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderPath & Filename)
            Application.AutomationSecurity = previousSecurity
    
            boolNotEmpty = False
            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.UsedRange) > 0 Then
                    boolNotEmpty = True: Exit For
                End If
            Next ws
            wb.Close False
            If Not boolNotEmpty Then Kill FolderPath & Filename
        
        End If
        
        Filename = Dir()
    
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: applied this code on my workbook to delete empty files in folder again getting same problem it's not deleting any empty excel files in that folder path why what the mistake from my side i don't understand

Comment: Code is working for me but again the check `WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.UsedRange) > 0` might not return what you think it should return.

Comment: i just copied full code into my workbook i didn't changed any thing in this code

Comment: So, code is running you just don't get your expected result. Please have a look at my remark above regarding **your check** on _empty_.

Comment: Yes I didn't get expected result & i have tried as you told above

Comment: Then your files are not empty by your check and  `WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.UsedRange) > 0` is true even if you think the file is empty.